# How to disable the "Next/Finish" action button when using Google's ViewPager for screen slides?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I've been using Google's ViewPager for screen slides (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). If you're familiar with it, you know that, when held vertically, a normal-sized phone would display the buttons "Previous" and "Next" at the bottom. Tapping on these would move the page either back or forward, depending.

At the very first page, you'll notice that "Previous" is grayed out (disabled) and you can only move forward.

At the very last page, however, something different happens: "Next" changes to "Finish" and is still enabled (clickable), even though there's nothing that comes after it. This bugs me a lot. I want the "Next"/"Finish" button to be disabled but can't find a way to do it.

I tried `menu.findItem(R.id.action_next).setEnabled(false);` when the last page is reached, but that just came back as a `NullPointerException`.

How do I gray out the "Next" button like the "Previous" button is by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting a `NullPointerException`, except that maybe you're calling `Menu.findItem` in the wrong `Activity`. Make sure you're calling it in the `ScreenSlideActivity`. But as far as disabling it goes, you can do so by checking the current page against the total page count.

```
item.setEnabled(mPager.getCurrentItem() != mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

[Here's a video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2301775/example.mp4)

Comment: Your code there works great. Thank you. I don't know why I got a `NullPointerException` either, I did put it in `ScreenSlideActivity`.